# Using 3rd party packages on remote machine without download/install rights

Tags: python

I am SSHed into a remote machine and I do not have rights to download python packages but I want to use 3rd party applications for my project. I found `cx_freeze` but I'm not sure if that is what I need.

What I want to achieve is to be able to run different parts of my project (will mains everywhere) with command line arguments on the remote machine. My project will be filled with a few 3rd party python packages. Not sure how to get around this as I cannot `pip install` and am not a sudoer. I can SCP files to the remote machine

Answer (score 1):

easy_install can install packages in your home directory.

Replace `pip --install package-name` with `easy_install --user package-name`.

---

Update: `pip` also has a `--user` switch. Try:

```
pip install --user package-name
```

Comment: I get a permission denied with easy_install =/

Comment: Try `pip install --user foo`.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically useless if you don't have executable permission in the remote machine. You need to contact your administrator to obtain an executable permission.

In the case for the SCP files to the remote server, you may still be able to cp you files but you may not be able to execute it.

Comment: I am able to scp a maven project with 3rd party dependencies so I thought I can do the same by with python